# Update usando Json HTML e PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, json, mysqli

Bom dia Preciso fazer um update dos dados que estao na minha index 
[image: Formulario]

Eles sao carregados da seguinte forma

JavaScript

```
$("document").ready(function () {

function gerarFunctionario(obj) {
    return  '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 profile_details">' +
            '<div class="well profile_view">' +
            '<div class="col-sm-12">' +
            '<h4 class="brief"><i>' + obj.nomeCargo + '</i></h4>' +
            '<div class="left col-xs-7">' +
            '<h2 id="NumeFunc">' + obj.nomeFunc + '</h2>' +
            '<p><strong>Cargo: </strong>' + obj.nomeCargo + ' </p>' +
            '<ul class="list-unstyled">' +
            '<li><i class="fa fa-building"></i> Address: </li>' +
            '<li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Phone #: </li>' +
            '</ul>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="right col-xs-5 text-center">' +
            '<img src="../images/user.png" alt="" class="img-circle img-responsive">' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-xs-12 bottom text-center">' +
            '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 emphasis">' +
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"> <i class="fa fa-user">' +
            '</i> <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> </button>' +
            '<button id="atualizar" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">' +
            '<i  class="fa fa-user"> </i> atualizar' +
            '</button>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';





}
var data2 = [];


$.getJSON('../include/carrFunc.php', function (j) {
    var itens = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {

        data2 [i] = {"idFuncionario": j[i].idFuncionario, "nomeFunc": j[i].nomeFunc, "nomeCargo": j[i].nomeCargo}

    }


    var html = data2.map(gerarFunctionario).join('');
    $("#inicio").html(html);
    $('.carregando').hide();

    console.log(data2);

});

});
```

HTML

```
                                        <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                                        <div id="inicio" >


                                        </div><!-- fim da div principal-->




                                    </div>
```

PHP

```
<?php
 include "conexao.php";

 $sql = "SELECT f.idFuncionario,f.nomeFunc,f.endFunc,c.nomeCargo FROM 
 tbfuncionario f , tbCargo c  WHERE  f.fkCargo=c.idCargo ;";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 $data = array();
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 // output data of each row

 $data = $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );
 //print_r ($data);

 } else {
  echo "Nenhum resultado encontrado.";
 }
 $conn->close();
 //echo "<br>";
 echo json_encode( $data );

  ?>
```

Preciso que ao apertar o botao atualizar os dados que carreguei ir para outro forumalario de cadastro para fazer o updade

HTML de cadastro

```
<form id="formCad" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" novalidate>
                                        <fieldset>
                                            <span class="section">Dados do Funcionario</span>

                                            <div class="item form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Nome e Sobrenome: <span class="required">*</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                    <input id="txtnome" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-validate-length-range="6" data-validate-words="2" name="name" placeholder="digite seu nome" required="required" type="text">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>


                                            <div class="item form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" for="cpf">CPF: <span class="required">*</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                                    <input  id="txtcpf" type="text" onkeypress="return Onlynumbers(event)" maxlength=11  required="required"   class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-4">

                                                </div>
                                            </div>





                                            <div class="item form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" for="endereco">Endereço:<span class="required">*</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                    <input id="txtendereco" type="text"   data-validate-words="2" name="endereco" required="required" placeholder="digite seu endereço"  class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-4">

                                                </div>


                                            </div>


                                            <div class="item form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" for="cep">CEP: <span class="required">*</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-10">
                                                    <input id="txtcep"  type="text" onkeypress="return Onlynumbers(event)" name="cep" maxlength="8" required="required" placeholder="digite o CEP"  class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-4">

                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="item form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" for="complemento">Complemento: 
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                    <input id="txtcomplemento" type="complemento"  name="complemento" placeholder="digite o complemento"  class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-4">

                                                </div>

                                            </div>





                                            <div class="item form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" for="bairro">Bairro: <span class="required">*</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                    <input id="txtbairro" type="text"  name="bairro" required="required" placeholder="digite o bairro"  class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-4">

                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="item form-group">
                                                <label  id="estado" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="textarea">Estado <span class="required">*</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                                    <select id="carrEst" >
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="item form-group">
                                                <label  id="cidade" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="textarea">Cidade <span class="required">*</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                                                    <select name="carrCid" id="carrCid">
                                                        <option value="">-- Escolha um estado --</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="item form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" for="dtaNascimento">Data de Nascimento:<span class="required">*</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <input id="dtaNascimento"  type="date" name="dtaNascimento" required="required" class="col-xs">

                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="item form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" for="Sexo:">Sexo:<span class="required">*</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <select id="cmbSexo">
                                                    <option value="Masculino">Masculino</option>
                                                    <option value="Feminino">Feminino</option>
                                                </select>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="item form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Email: <span class="required">*</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                                    <input id="txtemail" type="email"  name="email" required="required" placeholder="digite seu email" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">

                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                            <div class="item form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-4" for="dtaAdmissao">Data de Admissão:<span class="required">*</span>
                                                </label>
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <input  id="dtaAdmissao" type="date"  name="dtaAdmissao" required="required" class="col-xs">

                                                </div>

                                            </div>








                                            <!-------------------------------------------------------- Area reservada para  foreign keys -------------------------------->





                                            <div class="row">  
                                                <div class="item form-group">
                                                    <label id="departamento" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"  for="textarea">Departamento <span class="required">*</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                                                        <select id="carrDpto" >
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="item form-group">
                                                    <label  id="cargo" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="textarea">Cargo: <span class="required">*</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                                                        <select id="carrCarg"  name= "carrCid" >
                                                               <option value="">-- Escolha um Cargo --</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="item form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="salario">Salario: <span class="required">*</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                                                        <input id="txtsalario" type="text"  name="salario" onkeypress="return Onlynumbers(event)" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7">

                                                    </div>
                                                </div>



                                                <div class="item form-group">
                                                    <label  id="status" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="textarea">Status: <span class="required">*</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                                                        <select id="carrStatus" >
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                            <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->                                          





                                            <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cancelar</button>
                                                    <button id="btngravar" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Cadastrar</button>

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </form>
```

Comment: A sua intenção é ao clicar no botão atualizar, levar o usuário a uma página diferente da sua index ou nessa mesma página exibir esse formulário em algum lugar?

Comment: @PedroSouza Minha intenção e abrir em outra pagina.. que ja tenho ela pronta